# is there a Built-in function to check if one list is contained in another? in ELIXIR or ERLANG

Tags: erlang, elixir

Without using **brute-force** (i.e. checking element by element), is there a **built-in** function that can check if one list is contained within another?

Comment: what did end up using?

Comment: ordsets:is_subset(ordsets:from_list(List_Contained), ordsets:from_list(List_Containing)).

Comment: 1> L1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
2> lists:all(fun(X) -> lists:member(X, L1) end, MyList = "abc").

Comment: L1 == [X || X <- L1, lists:member(X, L2)]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a brute-force, and it has some limitations, but one might use [`Kernel.--/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2)

```
{l1, l2} = {[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]}
l1 -- l2
#⇒ []
l2 -- l1
#⇒ [4]
```

The exact requested checker would be:

```
Enum.count(contained -- container) == 0
```

Or, as noted in comments by @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil

```
contained -- container == []
```

Comment: It breaks for this: `[1,2,3] -- [1,2,4]`
`[3]` As such, extra effort required to ensure that it is a real sublist

Comment: @KevinJohnson I am not sure I follow. Not empty?—Hence not, one list _is not contained_ within another.

Comment: @mudasobwa should it not be revered? Enum.count(l1 -- l2) == 0

Comment: @mudasobwa where l1 is the smaller list we are checking is contained in l2

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu while your wording did not contain any `l1` and `l2`, it’s perfectly legit :) I mean, the last call above returns `true` if `l2` is fully contained within `l1`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are correct, I misunderstood your solution. Your latest edit made it more clear.

Comment: `contained -- container == []` would be far more efficient.

Comment: @mudasobwa you mentioned that it has some limitations, please can you give an example

Comment: I meant it is less flexible than the explicit `reduce`, one cannot e.g. make it work in set-way (assuming `[2,2,2] ∈ [1, 2]` etc.)

Comment: I see, it cannot be generalized. it will only work if containment is implied of the first element

Comment: Sorry, this will not work. Consider L1 = [1,2,2], L2 = [1,2]. Every element in L1 is in L2 but L1 -- L2 returns [2].

Comment: @RomanRabinovich sure it works. “Every element” has nothing to do with this question. Check what “list is contained within another” means.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'd love to know what you think it means and where you'd check such a definition.

Comment: @RomanRabinovich it means you might divide the containing list into the contained list and the rest where the rest might be empty. You might check the definition in any book on set theory (multisets chapter.)